# Запрос SQL для получения данных из таблицы

Tags: mysql, postgresql, select

Когда я делаю следующий SQL запрос не выводится ни одна запись из таблицы.

```
SELECT * FROM public.vk_group u
WHERE (u.city_name LIKE '%' OR u.city_name is NULL)
AND (u.country_name LIKE '%' OR u.country_name is NULL)
AND (u.region_name LIKE '%' OR u.region_name is NULL)
AND u.is_checked = True
AND (u.subculture_name LIKE '%' OR u.subculture_name is NULL)
AND (u.tag LIKE '%')
ORDER BY u.name
```

Когда я убираю какое-либо количество условий из этого кода, данные начинают выводится. Могу гарантировать, что в таблице есть записи, в которых `tag` не равен `NULL` и `is_checked` равен `True`.

Comment: В чем смысл условия u.tag LIKE '%' ?

Comment: Я делаю фильтрацию, если фильтр не выбран, то подставляется %

Comment: Нет. оператор LIKE сверяет текст в указанном поле u.tag с указанным шаблоном. % Значит любые символы в любом количестве. Правильней проверять как u.tag IS NOT NULL (если, конечно, это требуется) И ничто никуда не подставляется.

Comment: если ничего не выводится значит, очевидно, нет записей удовлетворяющих условию.

Comment: понял, спасибо большое